# Nothing in LOG , in android studio

Tags: android, logging

I am using Android Studio , and i am not able to view any on my log ,
I have also added the filter in the ***Devices section*** on "**Android DDMS**" to show the log files specifically of my current app (package ) .
**But log file does not shows any message of any log** .
Need Help !!!

Comment: It will and it should display try re-starting once.

Comment: I have tried re-starting entire Android Studio a couple of time , It didnt work out.

Comment: not android studio, only logcat window. You can google out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adb shell logcat in command prompt.

In ddms perspective just click on the name of the device showing then check the logcat output.